# Sort by a join table's column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a problem with rails syntax over getting something from database. I'm trying to run the following code:

```
list = Song.where(playlist:'true').order(:created_at).joins(:UserSong).order(:boost).limit(5)
```

but the attribute :boost is from the second table(UserSong) and it fails because it casts by default to Song.

How can i manage to set the boost attribute as being from UserSong table?

Answer (score 2):

You can do `.order('user_songs.boost')`:

```
list = Song.where(playlist:'true').joins(:UserSong).order('user_songs.boost').limit(5)
```

Comment: It seems I have no results because of where(playlist: 'true'), do you happen to know what is the right syntax?